# Spring Retry is not calling again for maxAttempts

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry

```java
 try {
        reponseType = retryTemplate.execute((RetryCallback<X, RetryException>) context -> {
            try {
                log.error("Calling api attempt #" + context.getRetryCount());
                HttpEntity<x> xResponse = httpRestTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, x.class);
                return xResponse.getBody();
            } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
                if (e.getStatusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
                    throw new RetryException("api returned Server Error", e);
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
 } catch (RetryException e) {
        throw  e;
```

Defined retryTemplate policy in configuration file and httpRestTemplate is normal template

```java
@Bean
RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(30000);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new CustomRetryPolicy(3));
    return retryTemplate;
}
```

But not able to call retryTemplate again after time given.
Can anyone help me, i think me getting confused in exception game.

Comment: I've found spring-aspects needs to be added as a dependency for spring-retry to work.

Answer (score 2):

This will only retry if `e.getStatusCode().is5xxServerError()`. Otherwise you are returning `null`, which is "success" from the retry template's perspective. The template will only retry when an exception is thrown.

You can classify which exceptions are retryable in the retry policy.

Comment: me getting 503 ServiceUnavailableException from restTemplate call but still retryTemplate is not working

Comment: Makes no sense; try running in a debugger to see what's happening when the lambda returns to the template.execute method.

Comment: I tried in debugging to see behaviour, so it's like restTemplate.exchange call api which in return HttpStatusCodeException  with ServiceUnavailableException i.e 503 then it throw RetryException. After that debugger goes into catch block catching RetryException and after throwing from there it goes to parent catch block.

Comment: That's just not possible; you must end up in the `RetryTemplate.doExecute()` catch block when stepping out of the lambda.